# Data mining and Business Intelligence Technologies

Tags: data-mining, business-intelligence

I've noticed an increasing number of jobs that are asking for experience with data mining and business intelligence technologies. This sounds like an incredibly broad topic but where would one go if they wanted to develop at least a partial understanding of this stuff if it were to come up in an interview?

Comment: I long for the good old days when 'data mining' was a shameful activity.

Answer (score 2):

A very good book with practical examples is the
[Programming Collective Intelligence: Building Smart Web 2.0 Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529325) by Toby Segaran.

Answer (score 1):

Go read [Data Mining: Practical Machine Learning Tools and Techniques (Second Edition)](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~ml/weka/book.html).
Then use [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~ml/weka/index.html) on a pet project. Despite the name, this is a good book, and the Weka package has several levels of entry into the data-m... er machine-learning world.

Comment: Thanks for the link to Weka. A lot of this stuff does feel reminiscent of topics that come up in university Statistics and AI courses.

Answer (score 0):

Consider reading [Ralph Kimball's books](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_ss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=ralph+kimball&x=0&y=0) for an introduction to Business Intelligence.
Also, try to not stick to one technolgy-vendor, every company has its own biased vision of BI, you'll need a 360 overview.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can also try to work with real BI - it is almost impossible to get in contact with data-filled and running SAS, MS, Oracle etc. I work in a team which integrates BI BellaDati for enterprises. For try-out and personal purposes it is free with some datastore limitations ( http://www.trgiman.eu/en/belladati/product/personal ).

BellaDati is also used as a learning tool on technical universities focused on practical application of data mining and analysis. The final manager-level dashboards examples of BellaDati can be seen at http://mercato.belladati.com/bi/mercato/show/worldexchanges

You can work here with SQL datasources, flat files, web services and play. From my own experience - to show real samples of market analysis practise (like case study etc.) is good for an interview.

I wish you luck,
Peter